# How do I schedule weekly notifications with data from EditTexts?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a very basic TimeTable app as a research project in highschool and have ran into some problems I can't find the solution for.

My main (and only, for that matter) layout consists of a TabHost which contains five tabs (monday - friday).

Each tab houses 6 rows (Six diffent times) of a Horizontal Linear Layout that contains two EditTexts: One for the title of the subject and another one for the class number. This is meant so the user can enter its personal data in the different edittexts. The notification scheduled for example on mondays at 8:00 should be build with the data from those EditTexts.

What I want to do is to create 30 weekly notifications, 6 a day from monday to friday. The time they have to be triggered at is pre-defined and the user will not be able to change it.

[Here is an image of the layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrG8z.png)

The basic code which is copied 30 times across the activity_main.xml layout:

```
                    <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="0dp"
                       android:orientation="horizontal"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/first_time"
                        android:textSize="20sp"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/subject_hint"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:inputType="number|textCapWords"
                        android:id="@+id/mon_subj_1" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/class_hint"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/mon_class_1" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_action_delete"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/button_description"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
```

In the MainActivity.java file I've only added the necessary code to set up the TabHost:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //creating the TAB HOST
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost2);
        tabHost.setup();
        //setting up the 1st tab
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("monday");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.monday);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Mon");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        //setting up the 2nd tab
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tuesday");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tuesday);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Tue");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        //setting up the 3rd tab
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("wednesday");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.wednesday);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Wed");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        //setting up the 4th tab
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("thursday");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.thursday);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Thu");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        //setting up the 5th tab
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("friday");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.friday);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Fri");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        //here we have finished creating the TAB HOST

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `AlarmManager` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeat Alarm once in a week in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237382/repeat-alarm-once-in-a-week-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the **Intent** that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running. *