# Repeat task in Tasker every other week

Tags: android, tasker

I wanted to know how to trigger a task every other week. Could any one please give me some step by step instructions how to do this? Btw, the task I want to repeat is a notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create your Tasker profile as you would normally do.
2. Then in the Tasker App Homescreen where all profiles are listed,  long press
   your desired profile.
3. Select settings icon from top nav that appears.
4. Under the new screen set *"Cooldown Time"*. **(in your case set it to 14 days)**

Now the Profile will fire up its tasks every 2 weeks. This is the best way to go about it.

---

A more tedious method,

### **1. Add New "Day" Profile**

[image: Add New "Day" Profile]

### **2. Select Week Day from drop-down**

[image: Select Week Day from drop-down]

**The Tasks under above profile will be repeated each week on Sunday midnight.**

PS: Not the correct place to ask such questions, you should check out https://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted it to repeat every second week.

Comment: Well the way i can think of this is by adding a "wait" Action under Day Profile  and set it to the time equal to 7 days. That should work.
You might want to change the Profile then or else it will be triggered on every selected week day & 7 days after each.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to elaborate on how to use the wait action?

Comment: After creating a "profile" (Application/Day/Evnet/Location/State/Time) as per your requirements,  create new "Task" which is basically a set of "actions" that u create. In Actions look for Wait Task to Stop executing the current Task for the specified amount of time (ms,s,m,h,day).
To create any profile, tasks etc. tap the "+" button at the bottom nav of tasker app.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create your Tasker profile as you would normally do. Then in the Tasker App Homescreen where all profiles are listed,
1. long press your desired profile.
2. select settings icon from top nav that appears
3. under the new screen set "Cooldown Time". (in your case set it to 14 days)

Now the Profile will fire up its tasks every 2 weeks. This is the best way to go about it.

Comment: When I long press on the profile, I can't seem to find the settings icon, only the rename, delete, export and select all options

Comment: Actually don't worry about it, I was in beginner's mode. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to set up a profile that is triggered based on Time. Then uncheck 'From' and 'Until', check 'Repeat' and set it to 336 hours (2 weeks).

Answer (score 0):

in android you can use alarm manager which will run after time interval you specify [You can check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237382/repeat-alarm-once-in-a-week-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, but I was talking about using Tasker automation

Comment: can you elaborate more. Is your task to send notification to user ?

Comment: Yep. It is to have multiple notifications per day on a 2 week cycle. ie week A notifications, week b notifications.