# How to send everyday notifications but only for a week?

Tags: java, android, notifications

One of the functionality on my app is to send a daily notifications at certain hour. It works properly but I woudl like to send these notifications only for a week and finish it after that.

I want to make it like that : user click the button and it activate sending notifications everyday for a week. Is there a posibility to count days or maybe how many times function was performed ? I have no clue how to make it..

This is my code :

Creating channel :

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel( CHANNEL_1_ID, "channel 1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

    }

}
```

Notification :

```
public class WeekChallengeBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyDBHandler myDBHandler = new MyDBHandler(context, null,null,3);
        ChallengesManager challengesManager = new ChallengesManager(context);

        int id;
        id = challengesManager.GetID();


        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_1_ID )
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentTitle( myDBHandler.loadChallengeNotificationRow1(id))
                .setContentText(myDBHandler.loadChallengeNotificationRow2(id))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000});

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        notificationManager.notify(2, notification.build());
    }
}
```

Function that activate notification :

```
void ActivateNotifications(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        if (calendar.getTime().compareTo((new Date())) < 0)
        {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), WeekChallengeBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        if(alarmManager != null){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use the alarmeManger please check this https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @Thompsonsparta I added the code

Comment: maybe you need to change the repeating interval to `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7`please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16237902/7085389